# How to get the iPhone slope degree accurately?

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer, acceleration

I need to know the slope of the iPhone as in "Compass" original iPhone app.

I tried the following code but it's not accurate and has problems.

```
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                         withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{

                        double slope = atan2(data.acceleration.z, data.acceleration.x)*180/M_PI;
                      });
                }
];
```

note: I need the iPhone to be in landscape mode.